# How to merge p tags into one line - beautfiulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

```
#Extract Record
for person in soup.find_all(['b','h1']):
    with open('test.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

        #Header
        header_tag = soup.find_all('h1')[k]
        k += 1
        header = header_tag.text.strip().replace('\n', ' ').encode('windows-1252', errors='replace')
        print(header)

        #Name
        name_tag = header_tag.find_all_next('p')[1]
        name = name_tag.text.strip().replace('\n', ' ').encode('windows-1252', errors='replace')
        print(name)
        #writer.writerow([name])

        #Workplace
        workplace_tag = name_tag.find_all_next('i')[0]
        workplace = workplace_tag.text.strip().replace('\n', ' ').encode('windows-1252', errors='replace')
        print(workplace)
        #writer.writerow([workplace])

        #Abstract
        while workplace_tag.find_all_next('p')[l] != 'h1':
            abstract_tag = workplace_tag.find_all_next('p')[l]
            abstract = abstract_tag.text.strip().replace('\n', ' ').encode('windows-1252', errors='replace')
            l += 1
            print(abstract)
            #writer.writerow([abstract])
```

The code above outputs what I need. Except there is one problem, when I try combining the p tags of the while loop at the bottom of the code in Abstract, I run into problems.

Using `print(abstract, end='')` does not work as expected.

And using this method:

```
#Abstract
        abstracts = ''
        while workplace_tag.find_all_next('p')[l] != 'h1':
            abstract_tag = workplace_tag.find_all_next('p')[l]
            abstract = abstract_tag.text.strip().replace('\n', ' ').encode('windows-1252', errors='replace')
            l += 1
            abstracts += abstract.decode('windows-1252', errors='replace')
            print(abstracts)
            #writer.writerow([abstract])
```

This code almost works however it makes my while loop always true and so infinitely prints the same first group of p tags.

An output of what I might get currently with my code is:

```
Name
Workplace
Abstract A
Abstract b
Abstract c
```

However I need it to look like:

```
Name
Workplace
Abstract A, Abstract b, Abstract c
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of a document ?

Comment: I have updated my question if that helps?

Comment: Without an url to get a sample of the text you're trying to parse, I can't really run your code properly. A few elements however:
- you never use your variable `person`
- I guess the `print(abstracts)` should be out of the while loop otherwise it will print the string each time an element is appended.

Comment: Please could you also add the URL, we could then test your code.